# Postges makes Seq Scan instead of Index Only Scan for a very simple SELECT x ... ORDER BY x

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan, database-indexes

I have a table `union_events` with 17M rows and 102 columns in Postgres 10. I run the commands:

```
CREATE INDEX union_events_index ON temp_schema_to_delete.union_events(id)
ANALYZE temp_schema_to_delete.union_events
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM temp_schema_to_delete.union_events ORDER BY id
```

and get the following results:

```
Sort  (cost=3614290.72..3658708.19 rows=17766988 width=4)
    Sort Key: id
    ->  Seq Scan on union_events  (cost=0.00..1474905.88 rows=17766988 width=4)
```

`id` is some non-null and non-unique integer field.

I expect that my index will be used and I haven't to sort the table once more.

I made a quick test:

```
SELECT s INTO temp_schema_to_delete.test FROM generate_series(0, 10000000) AS s
CREATE INDEX test_index ON temp_schema_to_delete.test(s)
ANALYZE temp_schema_to_delete.test
EXPLAIN SELECT s FROM temp_schema_to_delete.test ORDER BY s
```

It gets:

```
Index Only Scan using test_index on test  (cost=0.43..303940.15 rows=10000048 width=4)
```

It seems okay.

What is wrong with my first table or query? Why the index on `id` is not used?

Comment: `id is some non-null and non-unique integer field.` *How* repetitive ?

Comment: @joop Top-5 IDs has 13917, 4317, 2187, 2175, 1992 rows.

Comment: For both queries, issue `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. **If** the chosen plan actually is worse than optimal, take a look at the tuning constants {effective_cache_size, random_page_cost, work_mem}

Comment: In the quick test query, can you try using `generate_series(10000000,0, -1)` ?

Comment: @Ankur the same results: Index Only Scan using test_index on test  (cost=0.43..303939.12 rows=9999979 width=4)

Comment: There is `pg_statistic.stadistinct`. its value is -1 for unique columns (**!1!!1**) and the (approximate) number of values when above zero. (BTW: IIRC, there could also be an effect of the free space map; VACUUM is your friend)

Comment: @joop here are results for the current query:
Sort  (cost=3612141.58..3656520.01 rows=17751372 width=4) (actual time=50601.327..52535.028 rows=17751373 loops=1)
  Sort Key: qid
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1618528kB
  ->  Seq Scan on union_events  (cost=0.00..1474749.72 rows=17751372 width=4) (actual time=0.022..35783.612 rows=17751373 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.116 ms
Execution time: 53835.531 ms.

How can I make ANALYZE for index-only scan? Can I make a hint to a planner?

Comment: Okay, now try to do the same without seq_scan (`SET enable_seqscan = off;`)

Comment: @joop
Index Only Scan using union_events_index on union_events  (cost=0.44..460971.02 rows=17751372 width=4) (actual time=0.050..6442.910 rows=17751373 loops=1)
  Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.150 ms
Execution time: 7549.363 ms.
n_distinct in pg_stats is 19960

Comment: [Please add the explain output to your question] The best hint to the planner is proper statistics (which you seem to have) + appropiate tuning. First step would be to set `random_page_cost` to a lower value , say `1.5` .

Comment: @joop thank for your help, but I have some questions left, just to understand:
1. I set enable_seqscan = on, but query plan doesn't return to Seq Scan. Is it because I made a VACUUM or planner got some statistics (which one?) from somewhere else?
2. Does VACUUM matter in my case? I've made my table using single SELECT INTO TABLE and haven't made any inserts, updates or deletes.

Comment: Vacuum removes dead tuples and updates the FreeSpaceMap, I think that could change the estimated cost for the plans, and pick a different final plan. [please see releted questions]

Answer (score 0):

As @joop recommended, I've made a VACUUM for the table.

It resulted in a better plan that uses my index.

For me still it's not clear, how VACUUM could help with repsect to the fact that I've created this table using SELECT ... INTO TABLE and haven't done any UPDATEs or DELETEs.

It would be great if somebody could explain this in other answer, maybe there exists some effective solution then VACUUM.